# Sci-fi story about an astronaut rafting down a river in a primeval forest

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A few days ago, while cleaning up my library to donate some books to Goodwill, I found a piece of paper in one of the shelves with the word "SEHRALT". Then I remember that I have taken that word from a story in a 80's science fiction magazine digest-size, but I don't think it was an Asimov's SF magazine. The story was in English about an astronaut rowing in a raft down a long and solitary river surrounded by a primeval forest. The astronaut finds in one of his pockets a small empty vial labeled "sehralt". The astronaut doesn't remember who he is or where he was. He made an effort to remember and started to have flashbacks of a space travel and a wreckage. The other thing I remember was the astronaut realizing he cannot die and that he probably is the only human being on the planet.

I tried to make a sense of sehralt. I believe is German for sehr (very) and alt (old) but I couldn't find any reference on internet.

Also, in order to remember the story, I have questioned myself: Did the astronaut inject himself the vial to survive a long space travel and returned to Earth after eons? But, I don't remember anything of it and that's why I am looking for this story.

EDIT: I remember the story had a cover and a title. I don't remember the title but the cover was a black and white illustration of the astronaut standing on the raft in the middle of the river. Curiously, I found in my search of the story a photo that resembles the illustration but with a boat instead of the raft. Small world.

[image: Surreal Boat photo by Allvision]

Comment: You are almost correct with your guess about the german translation of "very old". Just note that in german it's also two words: "sehr alt". Maybe this can help you googling.

Comment: You've tagged this [books] but you say you read it in a digest magazine; should it be tagged [short-stories] instead?

Comment: @DavidW - You're right. It should be [short-stories]. I just updated. Thanks.

Comment: Could this be the RiverWorld series by Philip Jose Farmer?